# Адаптивный дизайн для Adsense

Tags: javascript, google-adsense

Здравствуйте. Хочу реализовать разные типы объявлений Adsense на разных экранах.

Сделал 3 объявления 336*280, хочу чтобы они в одну строку показывались на больших экранах. На экранах меньше 1200 должен показываться другой вид объявлений - адаптивное. Добавил их в один блок, скрываю с помощью медиазапроса через display:none, но здесь проблема - всегда объявления помещаются только в первые 2 места, не взирая на display:none.

Как правильно это настроить?

Answer (score 0):

В adsense на сколько мне известно, есть новый тип обьявлений - reponsive. Которое самостоятельно адаптируется под ширину экрана.

Comment: действительно есть, но стоимость показа таких объявлений низкая (по отзывах более прибыльные блоки фиксированного размера). Поэтому я хочу сделать чтобы на больших экранах отображались блоки фиксированного размера, а на маленьких - reponsive.

Comment: Разницы нет, установите responsive, а далее установите тип - только текст. Но если Вы настаиваете, то здесь есть два варианта, а именно, один обвернуть ваш код div-ов, в котором указывать где отображать, а где нет с помощью xs lg (bootstrap). Если без bootstrap тогда нужно будет использовать javascript для детекта разрешений экрана и т д. В общем вашу затею легче решить responsive либо bootsrap. Решение с JS более сложно, так как там нужно будет детектить все виды экранов, и разрешений +-.

Comment: как раз этот вариант я и пробовал реализовать, и о проблемах его реализации я написал в вопросе ....